# Trying to evaluate integral using cylindrical basis vectors

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, integration

To better explain my question, I'll describe the problem that gave me the idea, using that the eletric field for a linear distribution of charge is: $$\vec E = \int_L{\frac{k \cdot \rho_{l} \cdot dl}{|\vec r|^{2}} \hat r}$$
Find the eletric field on the center of a semi-circle (going from $0$ to $\pi$) with radius $a$ and constant $\rho_{l}$. I solved this using that $\hat r = \hat x\cdot \cos(\theta) + \hat y\cdot \sin(\theta)$ and $dl = a\cdot d\theta$, however, the answer uses the $\hat x$ and $\hat y$ unit vectors. Without converting the answer after solving it in cartesian form, is there a way to get the answer in terms of $\hat r$ and $\hat \theta$ directly from the integral? I saw on the book that $-\hat r = \frac{d\hat \theta}{d\theta}$ but I don't understand if it is possible to get a vector in cylindrical form directly from a integral (getting that the eletric field is for example: $\vec E =\hat r \cdot \text{Field Strenght} + \hat \theta \cdot \text{Field angle} $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not really possible because the polar basis vectors change with position. Therefore, you cannot integrate the $r$ or $\theta$ components directly.
$$\int_{C}\left(E_r\hat{\mathbf{r}} + E_{\theta}\hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}} + E_{\phi}\hat{\boldsymbol{\phi}}\right) \mathrm{d}l \neq \hat{\mathbf{r}}\int_{C}E_r \mathrm{d}l + \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}\int_{C} E_{\theta} \mathrm{d}l + \hat{\boldsymbol{\phi}}\int_{C} E_{\phi} \mathrm{d}l$$
You have to consider the components with respect to a fixed basis.

This is also mentioned in section 1.4 of Griffiths' *Introduction to Electrodynamics*.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm using the book that my professor recommended but I don't like the calculus review it has. Griffiths's book seems a lot more complete.

Comment: @FernandoHenriqueVazMello I get what's going on here now, and you know, our electromagnetism text never touched on that subject either.